# Database with a single table?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm creating a tool which scrapes Craigslist posts for certain criteria. If there is a new post, it will send an email. The tool will ultimately be run periodically with cron.

At first, I thought about storing the post contents (link, title, content) in a database. Then, for each invocation of the tool, it will scrape all of the posts it can find and check against the database to see if it is actually new.

This would mean a database with a single table (posts) and four columns (id, link, title, content). Is this overkill for this application? With a single table, there are no relations so a relational database has limited usage. Would a flat file serve better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to know if the post is new, then you can just store a hash value of the post content to a file.  When you rescan new posts, compute their hash and if the value isn't in the file it is new.  Add that hash to the file when you've sent your email.

To prevent the file from growing too huge, you could put dates on the values and discard them after certain time. A more elegant way would be to discard any hash values that were not found again in the most recent run.